# How can I tell if my Amazon Windows instance was an SQL Server AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to purchase some reserved instances, because I have several instances already created and running 24 hours a day. When I go to purchase a Windows instance, I can see 3 options,

- Windows
- Windows with SQL Server Standard
- Windows with SQL server Web

I don't know which of these was used to create the original instance. Is there a way I can find out?

My assumptions: the instance type is is important because as far as I understand, the way to purchase a reserved instance is to first have a running instance, and then purchase a matching reserved instance. The reserved instance is not itself a new machine, but a kind of contract between you and Amazon to pay for an instance for 1 or 3 years, at a discounted rate. The contracted, reserved instance will "offset" one matching running instance where they have the same *size* and *platform*. Please feel free to correct me if these assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Find the AMI ID and Google it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the status of a particular service bought from a specific vendor, and should be answered by the vendor support.

Comment: that's ridiculous @JennyD - almost all software and infrastructure questions are related to some vendor, open source or otherwise - if you take these questions away what will be left? How does the amazon-web-services tag have 194 followers and over 1378 related questions?

Comment: Your question is essentially "I have this service that I bought but I'm not sure what it is, how can I tell what it is?" It seems to me that the obvious answer is "read your contract; failing that, check with the organization with whom you have the contract".

Comment: @MichaelHampton that worked, if you add as an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just look for the AMI ID (it's in your list of instances) and Google it. It always returns a result in the Amazon marketplace.

Comment: If you created your instance from a snapshot, it's harder to find out.